# Dialogs narrow in PhpStorm after update

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, phpstorm

I have an annoying problem. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.
After upgrading PhpStorm to 8.0, all the dialog windows are very narrow by default. For example, the Git commit window:

http://minus.com/lZUSni9bWyRXq

The same goes for the settings window and similar. I don't know why this is happening or if there is a setting for this I can change. I can't find it.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got in touch with their customer support. The solution was to upgrade Java to the latest Oracle version.